# Pdo Dblib Mssql Connection Error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am using my sync system for 2 years. And i didn't change anything. wierdly today sync system is broken. And i recieved an error message.

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)
```

I google it.

And i learned it about freetds version problem.

For checking it

I wrote this line in ssh

```
TDSVER=7.0 tsql -H 78.***.***.49 -p 1433 -U DBNAME
```

I recieved this message.

```
locale is "tr_TR.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from *****SERVER Line 1:
    "Login failed for user 'DBNAME'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Same mistake.

I'm using dblib for connection via pdo.

What should i do ? What is the problem ?

UPDATE:

I read this part in [php manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

"If it is not possible to use SqlSrv, you can use the PDO_ODBC driver to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases, as the native **Windows DB-LIB is ancient, thread un-safe and no longer supported by Microsoft.**"

**My Free Tds Settings**

```
Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ridiculous. But i found the problem.

"enforce password expiration" was on. And windows forces to change db password. When i disabled it, we solved the problem.